# Impossible looking solder points on NRF24L01+ module

Tags: soldering, nrf24l01

[image]

I cannot even fit two dupont connectors side by side.
I am really quite uninitiated in electronics, being a software developer.
Is this an industry standard or some sort of way to connect this?
It's the first time I've encountered so small gaps.

Comment: The same modules are available with already soldered in headers FYI. It's most likely for 50mil pitch pinheaders. Small but not impossible. However availability of cheap cables and adapters is problematic.

Comment: Thanks. I may get some of those ones you suggest. Too bad I ordered six of these on hand. Maybe i can make do, or stick them on another PCB.

Comment: Those are definitely also meant for soldering into a PCB. Regular pinheaders are 100mil pitch, so if you have some you can easily check if my guess is correct. There's a chance the pitch is completely random, if it's meant for soldering only.

Comment: Thanks again. I do mean to solder it, perhaps solder some ultra thin solid core wire stripped on one end with connectors for test hookups on the other?

Comment: Yeah that'll definitely do for prototyping. Doesn't have to be ultra thin, just enough to still fit through the hole.

Comment: Also, you'll do well to get a small vise that you can pad. Use this to keep the pcb steady. This will allow you to control the solder and iron without the board sliding around.

Answer (score 1):

This module was meant to be soldered on main PCB which would usually be custom for your application.

I find its best to solder with ribbon cables between this module and your board. You would want to use short and thin wires (say 28 AWG). This will allow you to keep SPI speeds up. Solid core wires may not make good solder bond but might be ok for your application.

If other end of this cable needs to meet an Rpi/Arduino or similar board, you might want to cut dupont cables mid-way and solder open end to module and use connector end for your microcontroller board.

Soldering tip:
Hold module and cable steady in position to solder. Use vice and third hand.
Apply solder paste (not the flux) to base of wire on solder side.
Use hot air gun to finish soldering. Use a aluminium sheet to shield rest of the module from hot air, else other components will fall off.